# how to display values of a multidimensional associative array using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, associative-array

I have a Multidimensional Associative array and want to access any value from the array using `foreach` loop.

```
$a = array('Name:' =>'Khan',
       'City:' => 'Dubai',
       'DOB:' => '1992',
       'Father' => array(
           'Father Name:' => 'Jan',
           'Nic:' => '21105-2111336-3'
       ));
foreach($a as $key => $value){
    echo $key.' '.$value.'<br>';
}
```

I have tried this but it's only accessing the main array i don't know how to access the internal ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function array2string($ary, $depht=0)
{
    $output = ""; // string that represents your array
    $prefix = ""; // spaces to print before "key value"
    for ($i = 0; $i < $depht; $i++) // print as many spaces "\t" as how deep we are in the array
    {
        $prefix .= "\t";
    }
    foreach($ary as $key => $value)
    {
         if (is_array($value))
         {
             // if $value is an array print it with this same function
             $output .= array2string($value, $depht+1);
         } else
         {
             // else, simply append "key value"
             $output .= $prefix . $key . ' ' . $value . '<br />';
         }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Now this code:

```
$a = array(
            'Name:' =>'Khan',
            'City:' => 'Dubai',
            'DOB:' => '1992',
            'Father' => array(
                                'Father Name:' => 'Jan',
                                'Nic:' => '21105-2111336-3'
                       )
                    );


echo array2string($a);
```

Outputs:

```
Name: Khan
City: Dubai
DOB: 1992
    Father Name: Jan
    Nic: 21105-2111336-3
```

Comment: Thanks @Busy_Beaver